# Identify this game with darklings

Tags: game-identification

I played this game for the PlayStation 3 ages ago, and forgot all about it till just now when I saw this image:

[image: Game Screenshot]

I can't remember the name of the game to save my life. Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure that's either the darkness 1 or 2.

Comment: Yep, that's one of the *Darkness* games

Comment: A quick Google Image search tells me that this game is [Kobe Bryant Leather Jacket](http://bit.ly/1mTxbCZ). But really, it is *The Darkness*.

Comment: Well, I'm 100%, so I'll answer it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The image in question is from *The Darkness II*.  (The tentacle appendages are different looking between the two games, if you ever need to tell them apart.)